# Does speed of sound in air change if it is enclosed vs. open air?

Tags: pressure, acoustics

To calculate the velocity of a pressure wave (sound) in a fluid, I came across the equation

$$ c = \sqrt{ \frac{K}{\rho}} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

where $K$ is bulk modulus and $\rho$ is density.

My question is, if density of air stays constant, does bulk modulus of air change if it is free air vs. enclosed air? E.g. still air in a room vs. the air in the bell of a French horn.

Comment: Please use the MathJax syntax to make your math expressions readable.

Comment: The speed of sound does not change between open air and closed room.

Comment: Also the compressibility does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Speed should not change, the way reflections occur on the edge and form resonant frequencies and similar phenomenons of the container is obviously a behaviour that would not be found in an open area however.